# Where is Polysphere?

Tags: mesh, add-on

Where is the **Polysphere** object in Blender 2.76b? I have already installed **Add Mesh: Extra Objects** add-on and can see new objects in add menu, but Polysphere is not there. I also tried following it on the [official page](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_PolySphere), but they say that the script is already part of Blender and is not needed to be installed from file. Clicking on the **Current version download** link opens a forum instead of the script.

Answer (score 6):

### Round Cube

I don't know if the codes comes from the "original" polysphere script, but with **Extra Object** add-on comes an operator called "**Round Cube**" which create a very similar geometry.

[image]

You'll just have to make sure to use the "**Quadsphere**" preset:

[image]

[image]

You can get the "original" polysphere script for pre-2.61 Blender version from the author [website](http://www.metalliandy.com/html/extra_scripts.html) and then append the object in your scene (if you want to use a more recent version).

It seems to be slightly difference between the loopcuts position of the object created with the two methods.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This almost is the answer. Is there any way to confirm that a "Round Cube" is geometrically the same as what they called a "Polysphere" and it is just the name that is different? Means if an online tutorial uses Polysphere, can I follow it with a Round Cube instead?

Comment: dotNeT, I did an online image search for "polysphere", and the images I saw, including the ones included on Blender 2.5x and 2.6x addons to add one to a Blender scene, all had very similar geometry to that pictured in Carlo's answer. For my purposes, anyway, they are "geometrically the same".

Comment: It really depends on the kind of tutorial you are following, but for the common usage (basemesh for sculpting), as @brasshat said, the shapes can be said having almost the same geometry.

Comment: I bet it's the tutorial about making a Basket ball "I guess by Blender Guru", I went through this, I had to figure out myself that Round Cube is Polysphere, with a new name.

Answer (score 0):

Poly-sphere is something special.  The symmetry loops on the poly-sphere should form a perfect polygonal circle made of edges with equal length.

Rounded cube or any sub-divided cube with a spherify modifier or manipulated to be spherical only give you an incorrect version of the poly-sphere.

Example, create a cylinder with 16 edges.  Create a perfect poly-sphere with same diameter and segments on the perimeter.  Cut the poly-sphere in half and remove the caps on the cylinder.  Match the half sphere onto the cylinder's open cap, and try remove-double with threshold distance of 0 or barely 0.  If what you created is truly a poly-sphere, it should merge perfectly with the uncapped cylinder.

Blender by default does not give you the perfect and real poly-sphere.  It should be possible to create perfect poly-spheres by codes.